# Access MySql database with Netty

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, netty

I am building a server using Netty and MySql. When a client connects to the server, sometimes (not always) the server has to query MySql to reply. I think I can query MySql safety with one of the following methods:

1) Using synchronized block for the code accessing MySql. That is the simplest way for me. However I worry if it is a good idea to block i/o threads (threads using for reading/writing data to clients)

2) Using an asynchronous MySql library (such as async-mysql-connector) to query MySql without blocking i/o threads

3) Using a build-in function of Netty to access MySql. However, I have no idea which functions are useful for my case

Can someone give me some advices please? Many thanks

Comment: Why do you need to synchronize your calls to the SQL server? Once you run into one of the requests requiring you to query SQL, does your application need the data resulting from the query to reply to any further request?

Comment: That is a game server. Users may need information from themselves as well as other people. Many information such as user profiles, game results, playing time etc will be written down and read continuously. The amount of data may be very large to read once to store in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

1) Even when accessing MySql synchronously (i.e. from a single thread that waits for the response after issuing a single call - like in JDBC), you typically don't need a synchronized block. The server synchronizes itself where necessary. If you need consistency, use a transaction. This should be possible even with an asynchronous driver - if it supports transactions. In any case, when you use netty, you should avoid executing lengthy operations (including but not limited to blocking calls to an external server) synchronously. This basically kills all advantages of netty (and other asynchronous architectures) over thread-per-call architectures like servlets.

2) I have seen (but not yet used) the following asynchronous MySql drivers for the JVM (there may be others):

async-mysql-connector (https://github.com/dgreenru/async-mysql-connector) implements a nio based MySql driver "on foot", i.e. with no further dependencies directly on the JVM nio API. The last commit is almost a year old, so it does not look very well maintained (or it is free of bugs).

postgresql-async (https://github.com/mauricio/postgresql-async) is written in Scala and based on netty. It provides an asynchronous MySql driver in addition to PostgreSQL. All examples and descriptions are in Scala, but theoretically it is possible that it can be used from Java, too. Alternatively, you could implement a small wrapper in Scala for your functionality. This seems to me to be the most active and complete project of the ones mentioned here.

adbcj (https://github.com/gamlerhart/adbcj) is an asynchronous Java database driver with - among others - MySql support. The project looks somewhat abandoned (last commit more than a year ago). The MySql driver has a dependency on netty (v. 4.0.6.Final - might work with newer netty 4.x versions) in its POM.

3) a "built-in" function of netty to access MySql does (afaik) not exist (and is not its purpose). Using plain vanilla netty would mean you have to implement an asynchronous MySql driver on your own which is not all too easy. However, you could start with one of the above mentioned projects and tailor it to your needs (e.g. newer netty version).

Conclusion: try to use one of the asynchronous drivers. If none fits your needs, try to execute (synchronous) JDBC calls asynchronously e.g. by using a ThreadPoolExecutor, which avoids blocking netty's worker thread.